# If two column values match then merge content

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet with over 15k rows to merge in some cases. I have no experience with Excel, VBA.

[image]

What I am trying to do:
Look in column A and D to see if both values match. In this case **Memory Grey** and **T-Shirt**.
When they match merge those values into the amount of times the value in column D contains that value.

In above example that would be two rows of **Memory Grey** and five rows of **T-shirt**.

I tried a program called Kutools with no result.

I'm not sure how I would do this with a formula. I found something like:

```
=VLOOKUP(value, table, column, FALSE)
```

I guess that's used to find matches and not merging/copying.

I tried VBA but that didn't work.

```
Sub Test()

Dim i As Long
Dim id As String

For i = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    id = Cells(i, 1).Value
    If Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = id And Cells(i + 1, 2).Value <> id Then
        Range(Cells(i + 1, 2), Cells(i + 1, 6)).Insert Shift:=xlDown
        Range(Cells(i + 1, 2), Cells(i + 1, 6)).Value = Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i, 6)).Value
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Take a look to `SUMIFS` Excel function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(You'll need to sort the rows first, so the rows with a description come first)

If there aren't repeats in the column 'Description', then you can use a formula like this in A6:

```
=VLOOKUP($D6, $A$1:$Z5, Column(), False)
```

You can then copy and paste the formula to each column with missing values and drag it down.

Edit: I failed to notice more columns to the right of H, updated formula to use `Column()`

Comment: This gave me an error! I have changed the formula a bit to `=VLOOKUP(L813:L1887;$A$1:$Z$811;COLUMN();FALSE)` (as per my sheet). So I had to use semicolons. Anyway copying this to each single column works perfectly. Thank you very much!!

Comment: You're welcome! Glad you were able to get it done auto-magically. Also, sorry about the formula not working, it's hard to visualize something like that :)